# Apply an user created function with two arguments to multiple variables

Tags: r

I need to apply an user created function to selected combinations of variables in a dataset.

Simple example:

```
x<-c(1:10)
y<-c(10:1)
z<-rep(2,10)
w<-cbind(x,y,z)

myfun<-function (a,b){
c<-a*b
return(c)}
```

How can apply myfun to - say -  (x,y) and (x,z)?

Comment: Try `myfun(w[,"x"],w[,"y"])` I assume you are getting stuck because `myfun(w$x , w$y)` does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Use `myfun( w[,"x"] , w[,"y"] )` or `myfun( w[,"x"] , w[,"z"] )`. The `$` operator won't work on the data you posted above (I don't know if that is what you were trying to do) as it is used to select a single element of a list (a `data.frame` is actually list of vectors, possibly of different class (e.g. `numeric` or `character`) whereas what you have is a `matrix`. There are no list elements to select from a matrix. A matrix is a 2-dimensional vector:

```
x <- 1:10
x
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

dim(x) <- c(5,2)
x
#    [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    6
#[2,]    2    7
#[3,]    3    8
#[4,]    4    9
#[5,]    5   10

colnames(x) <- c( "A" , "B" )
x$A
  Error in x$A : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

x[,"A"]
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

But we can convert it to a `data.frame` if we want and use `$` to select the appropriate *column*:

```
x <- as.data.frame(x)
x$A
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: @user2339110 you are welcome! If this satisfactorily answered your question please consider pressing the green accept tick next to the answer, that way this question will be removed from the unanswered questions stack and it helps to keep the site clean. You are under no obligation to do so though. Thanks!!